# Python: Determine which package contains the currently running code (in order to retrieve package resources)?

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-importlib

Learning about Python package resources. I understand I can include arbitrary files and directories in my package using `include_package_data`.

Let's say I write a package that contains a single class:

```
(mypackage / __init__.py)

from importlib_resources import files

class myClass:

    def getResource(self, filename):
        return files('mypackage').joinpath(filename).read_text()
```

Now I package up this code into an installable Python package using a `setup.py` file, and install it.

Now, another developer comes along and wants to subclass my class. That user is also going to package their code in a package and release it, with a dependency being my package. And they want the `getResource` function to pull resources from *their* package, not mine:

```
( otherpackage / __init__.py )

from importlib_resources import files
from mypackage import myClass

class myNewClass(myClass):

    def getResource(self, filename):
        return files('otherpackage').joinpath(filename).read_text()
```

This is hardly ideal, since the other developer must supersede the `getResource` method, copy my code, and just change the package name. (Edit: This could be accomplished with `super` and passing in the package name, but it's still an extra step and could be argued to violate the DRY principle)

---

**The question is:** Is there a way to get the name of the Python package that the currently executing code is part of? (Or perhaps a better approach would be determining which package a class belongs to) That way, my package could simply discover that it's now running inside a subclass of `otherpackage`, and get the resources from `otherpackage` appropriately. (I could code a fallback, so that if the user doesn't include a resource in their package, I can retrieve it from a default resource in `mypackage`).

In this example, I want code running in an instance of `myClass` to get `mypackage`, but code running in an instance of `myNewClass` to get `otherpackage`, so I can pass this as the parameter to `files()`. I'd expect that if the code were not running in a package, I could simply get `None` back, and handle that situation using a fallback utilizing `__file__`.

Put yet another way, I wish for a function such that if the developer directly instantiates `myClass` and the function is called in the class's code, it should pull resources from `mypackage`; if the developer instantiates `myNewClass` it should use that developer's package. If the developer instantiated `myNewClass` outside of a package, I should be able to detect that and fallback on locating resources by way of path composition with `__file__`. I would like this to happen without the other developer ever needing to explicitly provide the name of their package to my code - the DRY principle applies here.

---

Secondary question: if this second developer sets up their package in dev/link mode (using `-e` on pip install), will this work while they are developing the package? In other words, can the other developer use the `importlib.resources` library to access the files in their dev tree from their code transparently?

Naturally, I would document how developers who subclass the API must deal with package resources (e.g. where to put files), so they would simply follow any directory names or other conventions I built into `myClass`'s expectations.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the module where a certain class was defined you can use [`inspect.getmodule`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule):

```py
from importlib.resources import read_text
from inspect import getmodule

class myClass:
    def getResource(self, filename):
        return read_text(getmodule(self).__name__, filename)
```

If you want to take into account where a certain class gets instantiated, you'd have to rely on frame inspection, e.g. via [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack):

```py
from inspect import stack

class myClass:
    def getResource(self, filename):
        caller_filename = stack()[1].filename
        ...  # do something based on `caller_filename`
        return read_text(getmodule(self).__name__, filename)
```

However, you problem description sounds like [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) would be useful (see also [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)), where developers can just drop their own stuff into the namespace package. So only your distribution would contain the logic for picking up the various resources.